# Ansible: can't del user

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying del user with the same name on all my servers. I'm using

```
ansible all -m user -a "name=tim-g state=absent remove=yes" -s
```

After this, system ask me the sudo password, but it's no work, I get:

```
192.168.170.150 | FAILED >> {
"failed": true,
"msg": "userdel: Permission denied.\nuserdel: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.\n",
"name": "tim-g",
"rc": 1
}
192.168.170.151 | FAILED >> {
"failed": true,
"msg": "userdel: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.\n",
"name": "tim-g",
"rc": 1
}
```

and same on all other servers. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are using an incorrect sudo password or otherwise do no have permission to remove the user.

Can you log onto one of these machines and confirm you have sudo permissions?